# Sharing on FB not working

Tags: ios, facebook

When I try to share stuff on Facebook from my app, the "Post" button is not working. The cancel button on the left side is working, but the post button on the right is not.

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func saveToFB(sender: AnyObject) {
        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
            var facebookSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            facebookSheet.setInitialText("Share on Facebook")
            self.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried this out...

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
                let fbcomposer = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
                fbcomposer.setInitalText(text)
                fbcomposer.addImage(UIImage(named: myimg.png))
                fbcomposer.addURL(NSURL(string: iosLink))
                presentViewController(fbcomposer, animated: true, completion: {})
            }
```

The problem is in your code you are only setting the `InitialText`. There is some issue with fb that does not allow third party apps to set text when posting. In my case, it was adding the image and the link as well. But the text was not added.

Try adding links or images and see if the problem still persists.

Hope this helps. :)